# pygtk: overriding gtk.Paned.compute_position

Tags: python, pygtk

I have a HPaned that one of its children changes its size requirement frequently, since its text changes. The result is that the pane moves every time the text is changed. I'd like to override the Paned.compute_position method so that the size of the child will not decrease, just increase. However, I can't find a way to override it. Even

```
class MyHPaned(gtk.HPaned):
    def do_compute_position(self, allocation, child1_req, child2_req):
        print "Hi"
        return gtk.HPaned.compute_position(self, allocation, child1_req, child2_req)
gobject.type_register(MyHPaned)
```

doesn't work. Do you have a suggestion? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Overriding `gtk_paned_compute_position` is not possible, since that function is not virtual in GTK itself. Also, `gtk_paned_compute_position` is marked as internal and deprecated and is not called anywhere from GTK+-2.24.x sources. I suspect it was only exported so that you could find out the position of the separator, not to affect it through overriding.

Instead of attempting to override `HPaned.compute_position`, you should place into the paned a single-child container (e.g. a child of `gtk.Bin`) that implements the desired resizing policy by hooking into the `size-allocate` signal and calling `set_size_request` with the desired size. This will be automatically respected by HPaned.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I guess that another option would be to put the child in a gtk.Alignment and change its size request when the child sends the size-allocate signal. Anyway, I realized that I'm okay with just having a fixed request, so I put my child in an Alignment with a fixed width request.